# How to create a browser plug-in using C#?

Tags: c#, browser, plugins

how to create a browser plug in using C#? (something like Flash Player or Unity3d)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using C# only.

WebKit is C++-based, so you'd need at least a C++ wrapper in order to let the browser communicate with your code. Using a mixed-mode C++ DLL that talks to WebKit on one side and to your C# code on the other side should be considered.

[The WebKit site](http://webkit.org/) does not contain much docs (don't want to criticize, but I couldn't find much there when working with Chromium). Only [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Concepts/AboutPlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001248) explain plug-ins, but it looks very Apple-oriented. Sorry, not very helpful.